# Como arrastar elementos usando dragSort dentro de uma div com scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drag-n-drop

Preciso que os elementos sejam arrastados somente dentro de uma div que tenha scroll. Por exemplo:

HTML

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li><div>1</div></li>
    <li><div>2</div></li>
    <li><div>3</div></li>
    <li><div>4</div></li>
    <li><div>5</div></li>
    <li><div>6</div></li>
    <li><div>7</div></li>
    <li><div>8</div></li>
    <li><div>9</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
h1 { font-size:16pt; }
h2 { font-size:13pt; }
ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; margin-left:20px; overflow: auto}
#list1 { list-style-type:none; margin:0px; white-space: nowrap; width: 100%;}
#list1 li{padding:5px; width:100px; height:100px; display: inline-block;}
#list1 div{ width:90px; height:50px; border:solid 1px black; background-color:#E0E0E0; text-align:center; padding-top:40px; }
```

JS

```
$("#list1, #list2").dragsort({ dragSelector: "div", dragBetween: true, dragEnd: saveOrder, placeHolderTemplate: "<li class='placeHolder'><div></div></li>" });

function saveOrder() {
    var data = $("#list1 li").map(function() { return $(this).children().html(); }).get();
    $("input[name=list1SortOrder]").val(data.join("|"));
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VVVBk/11/)

Arrastar a primeira lá para a última posição, sendo com que o scroll da div acompanhe.

Como fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só [adicionar o parâmetro `scrollContainer`](http://dragsort.codeplex.com/):

```
$("#list1, #list2").dragsort({ 
    scrollContainer: "#list1", 
    dragSelector: "div", 
    dragBetween: true, 
    dragEnd: saveOrder, 
    placeHolderTemplate: "<li class='placeHolder'><div></div></li>" 
});
```

Comment: Haha :) Excelente... e eu a perder tempo a fazer à mão... `+1`, curiosamente o método nativo do plugin é meio buggy...

Comment: E eu tava estranhado... "será que o Sergio não vai responder essa?" :)

Comment: Também estava fazendo na não hahaha... +1

Comment: :) lol... respondi mas dei uma volta bem longa. Mas até acho que o meu código é menos buggy :P

Comment: Pois sim, vi algumas coisas estranhas, mas como só testei no Fiddle achei que fosse coisa dele... @Sergio

Comment: @brasofilo, valeu não tinha me atentado na documentação .

Answer (score 4):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lq8fb/

```
$("#list1, #list2").dragsort({
    dragSelector: "div",
    dragBetween: true,
    dragEnd: saveOrder,
    placeHolderTemplate: "<li class='placeHolder'><div></div></li>"
});

var onDrag = false; // criar uma flag para saber se o Drag está ativo 
                    // o MooTools tem esta flag nativa mas não encontrei no jQuery...

var $list = $("#list1"); // só para economizar
var dimensoesList = {    // aqui guardo a posicao e largura da DIV mãe
    posicao: $list.position().left,
    largura: $list.width()
};

function mousePressed(e) {
    onDrag = e.type == 'mousedown' ? true : false;;
}
$('#list1 li').on('mousedown', mousePressed);
$('#list1 li').on('mouseup', mousePressed); // tb para mudar a flag quando o mouse for pressado

$('#list1 li').mousemove(function (e) {
    if (!onDrag) return; // se não estiver em drag, abortar
    var posicaoMouse = e.clientX; // guardar a posição atual do mouse
    if (posicaoMouse < dimensoesList.posicao + 100) { // caso esteja à esquerda
        $list.stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: dimensoesList.posicao
        }, 200);
    }
    // estes dois animate deviam estar numa função à parte que recebe o valor do scroll
    // e eventualmente o elemento, se tiver mais listas... fica para você fazer :)
    if (posicaoMouse > dimensoesList.largura - 100) { // caso esteja à direita
        $list.stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: dimensoesList.largura
        }, 200);
    }
});

function saveOrder() {

    var data = $("#list1 li").map(function () {
        return $(this).children().html();
    }).get();
    $("input[name=list1SortOrder]").val(data.join("|"));
};
```

Comment: Mais a sua também funciona e serve para outros projetos +1

Comment: Woool, que aula! Obrigado Sergio.